# How to change TitleLabel for UIButton?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView with simple content:

The user can edit (delete) the cells when tapping the Edit button the standard way.

I need to change TextLabel from "Edit" to "Done" when the user clicked on "Edit" button.

```
@IBAction func editButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
    
    if tableView.isEditing {
        editButton.titleLabel?.text = "Done"
    } else {
        editButton.titleLabel?.text = "Edit"
    }
}
```

TitleLabel doesn't change. I need change titleLabel to "Done" when I the user pressed "Edit"

Answer (score 1):

Instance method [setTitle(_:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle) does the trick.

```
if tableView.isEditing {
    editButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
} else {
    editButton.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use ternary expression with `? :`

```
tableView.isEditing.toggle()

tableView.isEditing ? editButton.setTitle("Done", for: []) 
                    : editButton.setTitle("Edit", for: [])
```

...or its shorter version like @Fogmeister
proposed.

```
editButton.setTitle(tableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit", for: [])
```

Comment: With a ternary expression I think the format `editButton.setTitle(tablewView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit", for: .normal)` works nicely too.

Comment: Hi @Fogmeister, sure. ))